# Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea

I am having trouble setting up a PostgreSQL API using Spring boot.

I have set this project structure up several times before and looking through old projects i'm not doing anything that different from them, just different classes and relationships.

Ive tried adding some different dependancies im not having any luck.

here is the error which i found

2024-02-19T17:07:52.151Z  WARN 2851 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

here is my pom.xl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>Back.end</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Text based adventure</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and here is my DataLoader for the DemoApplication

```
package Back.end.demo.Components;

import Back.end.demo.Adventurer;
import Back.end.demo.Enemy;
import Back.end.demo.Location;
import Back.end.demo.Repositories.AdventurerRepository;
import Back.end.demo.Repositories.EnemyRepository;
import Back.end.demo.Repositories.TreasureRepository;
import Back.end.demo.Treasure;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Profile("!test")
@Component
public class DataLoader implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    AdventurerRepository adventurerRepository;

    @Autowired
    EnemyRepository enemyRepository;

    @Autowired
    TreasureRepository treasureRepository;

    public DataLoader() {

    }

    public void run(ApplicationArguments args){
        Adventurer mcfee = new Adventurer("McFee", 0, Location.TOWN, "Fists", 0, true);
        this.adventurerRepository.save(mcfee);

        Adventurer mjohnson = new Adventurer("Mary Johnson", 50, Location.GARDEN, "Longsword", 1, true);
        this.adventurerRepository.save(mjohnson);

        Adventurer raj = new Adventurer("Raj", 0, Location.FOREST, "Dagger", 0, true);
        this.adventurerRepository.save(raj);

        Adventurer greg = new Adventurer("Greg", 500, Location.CASTLE, "Battle Axe", 3, true);
        this.adventurerRepository.save(greg);

        Enemy goblin = new Enemy("Goblin", "Dagger", false, Location.GARDEN);
        this.enemyRepository.save(goblin);

        Enemy knight = new Enemy("Undead Knight", "Greatsword", false, Location.CASTLE);
        this.enemyRepository.save(knight);

        Enemy troll = new Enemy("Troll", "Club", false, Location.FOREST);
        this.enemyRepository.save(troll);

        Enemy jester = new Enemy("Jingle the Jester", null, false, Location.GARDEN);
        this.enemyRepository.save(jester);

        Treasure diamond = new Treasure("Diamond", 1000, null, Location.CASTLE);
        this.treasureRepository.save(diamond);

        Treasure sapphire = new Treasure("Sapphire", 500, null, Location.CASTLE);
        this.treasureRepository.save(sapphire);

        Treasure emerald = new Treasure("Emerald", 350, null, Location.GARDEN);
        this.treasureRepository.save(emerald);

        Treasure ruby = new Treasure("Ruby", 350, null, Location.GARDEN);
        this.treasureRepository.save(ruby);

        Treasure sandals = new Treasure("Winged Sandals of Hermes", 1000, null, Location.CASTLE);
        this.treasureRepository.save(sandals);

        Treasure coin = new Treasure("Gold Coin", 50, null, Location.FOREST);
        this.treasureRepository.save(coin);

        Treasure blackRuby = new Treasure("Black Ruby of Voldesadt", 1500, null, Location.CASTLE);
        this.treasureRepository.save(blackRuby);
    }
}
```

And here is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/adventurers
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

Comment: maybe it cannot connect to your database on localhost:5432

Answer (score 1):

In your `application.properties` replace:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

by

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

or

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Just like this [Guide](https://medium.com/linkit-intecs/connecting-a-springboot-application-to-a-postgresql-database-427364f48245)